# Return statement in if statement

Tags: xmlhttprequest, activexobject

I am experiencing some strange behavior in IE10.  I needed to use ActiveXObject to get some files locally (via the file:// protocol).

Why does this work in IE10:

```
function createXhr() {
  return new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
}
```

But not this:

```
function createXhr() {
  inMpage = true;

 if (inMpage == false) {
   var a = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
   var a = new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
 }

 return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because all modern browsers (**IE7+**, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera) have a built-in `XMLHttpRequest` object.

```
var a = new window.XMLHttpRequest(); // use this for IE10
```

and your code is executing `else` case which is compatible with old versions of Internet Explorer (IE5 and IE6) not with **IE10**.

```
var a = new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
```

To handle all modern browsers, including IE5 and IE6, check if the browser supports the `XMLHttpRequest` object. If it does, create an `XMLHttpRequest` object, if not, create an `ActiveXObject`:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```